# How to add list in the object under the corresponding keys instead of replacing the content?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, object

I came from PHP and can not perform in JS simple task of associative arrays can be done in PHP. Maybe I am using approach which does not fit with this language.

So, I have an object which I have to rebuild for further needs. The info is getting added in while cycle.

Lets say I have the following:

array[0] =    {
company: 'kfc',
position: 'chicken',
name: 'Andrejs',
age: '20 days'
}

array[1] =     {
company: 'kfc',
position: 'chicken',
name: 'Alex',
age: '15 days'
}

array[2] =     {
company: 'mcdonalds',
position: 'chicken',
name: 'Lena',
age: '23 days'
}

I whish to get the info in the following:

```
{
 {kfc: 
  {chicken: 
   {name: "Alex", Age: "15 days"}, 
   {name: "Andrejs", Age: "20 days"}
  }
 }, 
 {mcdonalds: 
  { chicken: 
   {name: "Lena", age: 23 days}
  }
 }
}
```

I have tried:

1. Create an object: `food = {};`
2. to create object like this (in while cycle):

```
food = {array[i].company : {array[i].position : {name: array[i].name, age: array[i].age}}}
```

This did not work, because it overrates the data which were written in previous while round.
3.  Create variable m to give an unique key:

```
food[m] = {array[i].company : {array[i].position : {name: array[i].name, age: array[i].age}}}
m++;
```

This did not work, because I had 3 separate strings in object.
4. To use a keys before = sign:

```
food[array[i].company][array[i].position] = {name: array[i].name, age: array[i].age}
```

This gives an error, because such keys does not exist during the first round.

I have checked some object tutorials, but did not find resolution. Will very thankful to those, who will point the correct way of creating associative objects in JS.

Comment: so you an want array[0], array[1], array[2] right just to clarify

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired output using [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), grouping on `company` and `position`.

For each item, we check if there are any existing entries for that key, if not we create them.

Each `position` property will contain an array of all entries for that position.

```js
    

let arr = [
    { company: 'kfc', position: 'chicken', name: 'Andrejs', age: '20 days' },
    { company: 'kfc', position: 'chicken', name: 'Alex', age: '15 days' },
    { company: 'mcdonalds', position: 'chicken', name: 'Lena', age: '23 days' }
];

const output = arr.reduce((acc, { company, position, age, name }) => { 
    // If no existing items are here, create an empty object for this company.
    acc[company] = acc[company] || { };
    // If no existing items are here, create an empty array for this position. 
    acc[company][position] = acc[company][position] || [];
    // Add the entry for the relevant position
    acc[company][position].push({ age, name})
    return acc;
}, {})

console.log(output)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function `groupEmployees` which will organize the array of employees into a hierarchical object:

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAogtmANgexBaBeKBvAsAKCigGNkEBDAOxAC4oBnYAJwEtKBzAbgKLGXpbAWySnUasO3QlErk4EMczZceUcuwUMlkggF8pBUJCgBhMmCogoWbFADafAUJGKJ7ALp0ACi2IBrAB54JFR0ABooAHJ1CEioAB8o2XlIgD47dyh9AgIAMwBXSmJnSih2JmR8sGCUNAh6KAAKCARa9Ho6GtCIDIBKOls7UgpqV2VPU3NLLJxVUkpGMoqqgfthi1GtNwmzEatdaxxs-FVc5CYm+cXbGIj1ywjkiAjHQWFSg+RcqBaQuvperNpERGo1ypUwEMptRMgB+WE2XS9Bz8N4iOEI+zuXoAOjA+XoAAtGjcNI85NAkVIiLoctImBBgPkmKVwVUpLSTvgrsAfq1uh1YPy6hlDnZVLZ7ptIn5csRIi9USU6JFiITfH4IJQFTIKSqAIKUAAmDIAVvQdTEVQAmAAMUCN5BAFqyYQlJGhtCisvliqc7xVao1Wp1TwNiAgAA9LRoVQBGACsDqdLt0bukks9KrgxCNInIiCNFr9aNEUSD-hD5PkKoAMlryDHNJFrQBmZPOuJpgjuAzckT0ZARnEodhg5bVYXtZpT+q9XpSIA)

```js
function groupEmployees (employees) {
  const group = {};
  for (const { age, company, name, position } of employees) {
      ((group[company] ??= {})[position] ??= []).push({ age, name });
  }
  return group;
}

const employees = [
  { company: 'kfc', position: 'chicken', name: 'Andrejs', age: '20 days' },
  { company: 'kfc', position: 'chicken', name: 'Alex', age: '15 days' },
  { company: 'mcdonalds', position: 'chicken', name: 'Lena', age: '23 days' },
];

console.log(groupEmployees(employees));
```